# How to create newsletter subscriber programmatically magento2

Tags: magento2, newsletter

How to create newsletter subscriber programmatically ? I have email id I want to save that email id in newsletter subscriber how can I do that ?

```
<?php

/**
 * Copyright 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace vendorname\moduelname\Model;

use Sapient\CustomApi\Api\CustomInterface;

/**
 * Defines the implementaiton class of the calculator service contract.
 */
class Custom implements CustomInterface
{

    protected $subscriberFactory;


    public function __construct(

    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory
) {
    $this->subscriberFactory= $subscriberFactory;

}
    /**
     * Return the sum of the two numbers.
     *
     * @api
     * @param int $num1 Left hand operand.
     * @param int $num2 Right hand operand.
     * @return int The sum of the two values.
     */
    public function add($num1, $num2) {
        return $num1 + $num2;
    }

    /**
     * Sum an array of numbers.
     *
     * @api
     * @param string[] $email The array of numbers to sum.
     * @return string The sum of the numbers.
     */
    public function newsletter($email) {

           //$data ="sssssssss"; 
          // print_r($data);
           //die;
        $this->subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($email);
        return $email;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To do that you can inject `Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory` in your constructor:

```
protected $subscriberFactory;

public function __construct(
    //
    \Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory $subscriberFactory,
) {
    $this->subscriberFactory= $subscriberFactory;
    //
}
```

Then in your code you can call:

```
$this->subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($email);
```

Comment: i updated my question with code i want to subscribe under newsletter function but i am getting error

Comment: How to subscribe first name ans last name?

Comment: Above code works but firstname and lastname values how we can pass?

Comment: @jafarpinjar the name of the subscriber is taken from the customer entity if one exists with that e-mail. Out of the box there's no way to set name values for guest customers as far as I can see.

Comment: can we not override and customize it?

Answer (score 3):

```
$email = 'test_email@gmail.com';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$subscriber= $objectManager->create('Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory'); 
$subscriber->create()->subscribe($email);
```

Comment: Dont use object manager directly. It's bad practice. Use dependency injection instead: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html.

Comment: what the correct way to use this function outside folder app. pls tell me I'm just curious.

Comment: The correct way is to not use this function outside the `app`-folder :-P. All of your (custom) code should reside in `app/code`. If you want to create a CLI command you can create one from within a module, which in turn provides proper dependency injection. See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/cli-cmds/cli-howto.html and https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-command. And when you have your own CLI command you can use DI as propes in Raphaels' answer.

Answer (score 0):

From Magento 2.4, store_id has to be provided. You have to use SubscriptionManagerInterface class.

```
use Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriptionManagerInterface;

/**
 * @var SubscriptionManagerInterface
 */
private SubscriptionManagerInterface $subscriptionManager;

/* @param SubscriptionManagerInterface $subscriptionManager */
public function __construct(
    SubscriptionManagerInterface $subscriptionManager
) 
{
    $this->subscriptionManager= $subscriptionManager;
}
```

And then in your function:

```
$this->subscriptionManager->subscribeCustomer((int)$customer->getId(), (int)$storeId);
```